# How to get rid of low battery warning message?

Tags: gnome, power-management

My application running on a laptop-like device is controlling battery status on its own but when laptop battery is critically low Gnome Power Management message box appears:

[image: low battery warning]

As my GUI style is totally different I would like to permanently disable / uninstall this Gnome feature. How to achieve this ?

EDIT:

I am on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: The package that handles the indicator is `indicator-power`. Please report back if that's the one that also stops the popup and I'll make it into an answer if it does  ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Is this package also present in Lucid ? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Nope but since you did not specify what Ubuntu I always use the latest ;) For Lucid follow Gaurav_Java's method!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by opening `gconf-editor`, and setting the key `/apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/low_capacity` to `false`

if u don't have gconf-editor then install it

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```