# How to show low battery warning message/notification on GNOME/Wayland/Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: gnome, power-management, laptop, battery, wayland

On a current Ubuntu with Wayland/GNOME, when my battery is low the battery indicator on the top right goes red. On my previous laptop I had Ubuntu/X/GNOME, and a popup notification used to appear indicating that the battery is critical and the computer is about to shut down. Now it just goes dark. Is there a way to re-enable such notifications?

I see no option in the power settings, GNOME tweak tool or dconf.

#### Related questions

I saw the reverse question [How to get rid of low battery warning message?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98659/how-to-get-rid-of-low-battery-warning-message) from 2012. Btw, gconf-editor does not seem to be installable anymore from Ubuntu (`gconf-editor` has no suggestions, `sudo apt install gconf-editor` does not find it), although it is alive and well in the online documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GConfEditor and https://help.gnome.org/users/gconf-editor/.

This is the same question as [No low battery popup notification in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800875/no-low-battery-popup-notification-in-16-04) and [Ubuntu 18.04 not showing low battery warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094761/ubuntu-18-04-not-showing-low-battery-warning)

This is different to

- [No warning for low battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345521/no-warning-for-low-battery) [No low battery notification appears before premature low battery shutdown on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092160/no-low-battery-notification-appears-before-premature-low-battery-shutdown-on-ubu) where the battery estimation is wrong
- [Ubuntu 18.04 not showing low battery warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094761/ubuntu-18-04-not-showing-low-battery-warning)  which gives help to set the hibernate action when battery is critical

It may be similar to:

- [Ubuntu 18.04/i3wm - No low battery notifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102706/ubuntu-18-04-i3wm-no-low-battery-notifications)  (which uses i3wm)
- [No Low Battery Notifications or Low Battery Action on 16.10/17.04/17.10/18.04.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837830/no-low-battery-notifications-or-low-battery-action-on-16-10-17-04-17-10-18-04-4) (unresolved)

Comment: See if `dconf write /apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/low_capacity true
` helps ... I haven't tested it and don't even know if it's still valid ... I simply took it from your first linked post as you seem to have great hope in setting that key, so that's how to set it in current versions.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1412220 as a template to write and implement your own notification solution.